# Conflict between Pinterest and Fancybox

Tags: javascript, fancybox, fancybox-2, pinterest

I have a page that has both Fancybox and a Pinterest pin button. Both seem to work as they should, but when I close the Fancybox overlay I see the following JavaScript error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data-pin-aha' of null
```

My Pinterest button renders as this:

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://www.mywebsite.com/somepage&amp;media=http://www.mywebsite.com/content/images/2c63a4e0-3b65-4464-934c-77f2a7166090-Dim459X612.jpg&amp;description=some description" class="PIN_1354830754034_pin_it_button PIN_1354830754034_pin_it_beside PIN_1354830754034_hazClick" data-pin-aha="button_pinit" data-pin-config="beside"><span class="PIN_1354830754034_pin_it_button_count" id="PIN_1354830754034_pin_count_0"><i></i>3</span></a>
```

Just for fun, my Pinterest button is being loaded asynchronously with this:

```
(function () {
window.PinIt = window.PinIt || { loaded: false };
if (window.PinIt.loaded) return;
window.PinIt.loaded = true;
function async_load() {
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.async = true;
    if (window.location.protocol == "https:")
        s.src = "https://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js";
    else
        s.src = "http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js";
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
}
if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", async_load);
else
    window.addEventListener("load", async_load, false);
})();
```

And my Fancybox link:

```
<a href="//vimeo.com/36573701" class="watch"><span>Watch Our Story</span></a>
```

Overall it's a pretty basic setup. Just for kicks I used the normal inline script tag for Pinterest, but got the same error.

Has anyone ever seen this error and know how to fix it?

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm using Fancybox 2.1.3 with jquery 1.8.3

Comment: Didn't manage to reproduce the issue using exactly the same code [check here](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/pinterestConflict_07dec12.html) ... maybe something else in your page but hard to say without a link. Could you create a sample page to see the issue?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue?

Comment: How come do you want to get help if you don't provide any feedback to the questions/comments provided!?!?!?! your code works fine as in the example provided **[HERE](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/pinterestConflict_07dec12.html)**

Comment: I have the same issue except my error is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data-pin-log' of null` which happens after I close FancyBox

Comment: @fkim : did you see my example? ... no errors; can you share a link to the page with your issue?

Comment: @JFK: I've been getting the issue described in the question in some of my code, but I *also* get it on your example page. (I'm using Chrome 25 on Windows, and the error appears in the Web Inspector's JavaScript console.)

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue with the Pinterest button. It turned out to be a problem with Pinterest's pinit.js script.

I’ve [reported the issue to Pinterest (sign in required)](https://help.pinterest.com/requests/1041252), and they’re looking at it.

We were using the Pinterest button on a page that had another link on it with a click event assigned. The link's HTML was, roughly speaking, like this:

```
<a href="#" class="youCanClickThis"><span>Select</span></a>
```

The click event handler was like this:

```
$('.youCanClickThis').click(function (e) {
    $(this).html('Selected');
});
```

This click handler was somehow causing an error in pinit.js (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data-pin-log' of null`).

I [unminified](http://jsbeautifier.org/) https://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js in order to trace the error more easily. It was showing up in this function in the unminified pinit.js:

```
get: function (b, c) {
    var d = null;
    return d = typeof b[c] === "string" ? b[c] : b.getAttribute(c)
},
```

Specifically, `typeof b[c]`. `get()` is called from `getData()`, and the value of `b` is passed straight through from whatever called  `getData()`. That turned out to be this function:

```
click: function (b) {
    if ((b = a.f.getEl(b || a.w.event)) && b !== a.d.b) {
        if (!a.f.getData(b, "log")) b = b.parentNode;
```

This appears to fire whenever the user clicks on anything on a page that has a Pinterest button. The last bit - `b.parentNode` - is what caused us problems.

By that point, `b` has been assigned to the element that the click event originated on. In our case, that was the `<span>` inside the `<a>`. However, because our JavaScript replaced the contents of the `<a>` tag with text, the `<span>` was no longer part of the document, and thus no longer had a `parentNode`.

Thus `b = b.parentNode` caused `b`’s value to be `null`.

We worked around this by not removing the `<span>` from the document on click. However, it would be good if Pinterest could add a check to see if `b.parentNode` exists, or something.

(I don’t understand the Pinterest script well enough to know what the best fix would be, but it’s built with the assumption that the source of a click event will always have a `parentNode`, which, as this demonstrates, isn’t a safe assumption).

Comment: I've [reported the issue to Pinterest](https://help.pinterest.com/anonymous_requests/new).

Comment: Their site is obnoxious. I gave up looking for a  dev portal. Is there a tracking URL for the issue or anything?

Comment: @ashack: I think they auto-closed my original issue because I didn’t reply to their initial auto-reply, but I’ve re-opened it now. It might be viewable at the following URL, although you may have to sign in with a Pinterest account (and, for all I know, *my* Pinterest account): https://help.pinterest.com/requests/1041252

Comment: @ashack: a Community Specialist from Pinterest has passed the write-up to their engineers.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but my particular node should have a `parentNode`.  It has a parentNode in Firefox. It is a `button` element that is the child of a `div`.  Also, I checked the above issue link and nothing is showing up.

Comment: @xdhmoore: sure - yeah I can't get to my help request either now, even when logged into Pinterest (the login link in the Pinterest help site header doesn't seem to do anything). If you're having a similar but different issue, I'd recommend asking a Stack Overflow question about it.

Comment: @Paul: Thanks.  I realized the parent was being deleted, but FF was still allowing access via the DOM, where IE wasn't for some reason.  However, I ended up fixing our problem.  Added a brief description in an answer below.

Comment: @xdhmoore: ah,okay. Glad you got it fixed, and good to get another approach documented.

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data-pin-log' of null` error on that page.

A hacky way to fix the issue would be to add an afterShow event that adds the `data-pin-log` attribute to the close button

```
  $(".watch").fancybox({
    helpers: {
        media: {}
    },
    afterShow: function(e){
        $('.fancybox-close').attr('data-pin-log', false);
    }
  });
```

This would also work for the OP's problem by replacing `data-pin-log` with `data-pin-aha`

Comment: I dug into this issue a bit more; you might want to have a read of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15616800/20578) to see if it helps your situation.

Answer (score 1):

We were having the same issue using jQuery Modal.  We solved the problem by adding an onHide handler that hid the modal window, waited a few seconds, and then deleted the modal window.  Not the prettiest solution, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Fix for this is pushing today; very sorry for the trouble. If you run into difficulties with pinit.js in the future, please let us know here:

https://github.com/pinterest/widgets/